# MYSQL56 command line client login error

Tags: mysql

I am entering mysql password. But It closes the window immediately after displaying the error for just few milliseconds. How do i see that error?

Its' Mysql command line client

Comment: Is that terminal window? Command-line prompt? Please be more specific..

Comment: Check that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508420/mysql-command-line-wont-open did you set a password?

Comment: Yes. It worked yesterday. I canged some firewall settings. After that I couldn't open this. But Service is running

Comment: Then you may consider changing the firewall permissions for that service.

Comment: Where is the server, client give details

Comment: Localhost @DrewPierce

Comment: give details of the setup and what you have done

Comment: I guess it's not that important